# Typescript enums assigned to a Mongoose enum?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, enums

We have a Typescript based NodeJs project that makes use of Mongoose. We are trying to find an appropriate way to define an enum field on a Mongoose schema, based on a Typescript enum. I did look through the docs, but I could not find anything of note.

Taking an example enum:

```
enum ETransactionType {
    Buy = 'buy',
    Sell = 'sell',
}
```

and a Mongoose schema:

```
const TransactionSchema = new Schema({
   user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
   transactionType: {
      type: ETransactionType,
      default: ETransactionType.Buy
   }
});
```

Is this sufficient or should we also be extracting the values from the TS enum, such that:

```
transactionType: {
   type: ETransactionType,
   default: ETransactionType.Buy,
   enum: Object.values(ETransactionType)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer:

You need to use the second option.

Also, the `type` should be `String` instead of the enum itself.

```
transactionType: {
   type: String,
   default: ETransactionType.Buy,
   // no need to use Object.values(ETransactionType) after v5.11
   enum: ETransactionType
}
```

### Long answer:

The first is sufficient in terms of development time, but won't run the `enum` validator in runtime. Which is why you need to have the `enum: Object.values(ETransactionType)` part, it will not be added automatically to the schema definition.

Also, it's worth noting that mongoose currently does not support TypeScript, [we're planning to have official TypeScript definitions in version 5.11](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8108).

Comment: Coming back to this after seeing the answers in the project's GitHub [issue tracker](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9535), the short answer seems wrong, since the 'type' should be String or whatever the value type of the enum is.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. 